# Through what exercise can you finally see scales underneath chords?

Tags: guitar, chords

I have come to a point where I can identify major scale shapes and chord shapes including inversions.

But I cannot see them both at the same time.

What exercise will help me see them both at the same time?

Comment: Since there are multiple shapes for any given chord or scale, can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Problem is, on guitar, often chords do not play each and every note of a chord sequentially, often certain notes are omitted, so you'll rarely be able to see more than snippets of how they interact with each other.

Comment: I tuned my guitar to all fourths. It makes me see and feel the chords and pitchsets for a scale clearer. I then play the chords in a way so I always include one octave (at least two ways to do this for major and minor chords with reasonable max fret distance) and jump around between all chords which are fully inside the pitchset. This etches the major and minor chords stronger into my memory. Then I switch instrument and get confused again... The major second from the root is especially easy to remember, because there are a whole steps around it so its right in the middle like an X.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know for sure if this will completely answer your question but based on your guitar tag I’m providing a chart with the 5 basic major scale positions. I have superimposed each of the 5 basic CAGED chords over the corresponding scale positions in blue highlighter and labeled each one with red text. This shows where all the scale notes are for each of the 5 basic major chord shapes.

[image]

Comment: Much as I dislike the dotty 'scales' plans given for guitar, this shows the relationship between scales and chords as best iy can. There is a  guy from the Antipodes who represents the shapes with pictures - a running man, etc, but I'm not totally sold on the idea. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can practice scales in ways that emphasize chord tones.

1. Play up the scale in thirds then back down by steps, then reverse those two directions. `C E G B D F A C, C B A G F E D C B A G F E D C` and `C A F D B G E C, C D E F G A B C D E F G A B C`
2. Play "turns" or auxiliary tones on chord tones, ex. `C B C, E D E, G F G, B A B, C` which essentially plays chord tones with the other tones filling in the thirds. You can also do things like `C D E, E F G, G A B, C` where you fill in between the chord tones with passing tones.
3. Play scales but rhythmically emphasize with long note values the chord tones. Ex. `C...D, E...F, G...A, B...C, C`.

The basic concept that links all these ideas and will help you see the "scales underneath the chords" is thinking of scales as chord filled in with passing tones.